# how to parent my sun to environment hdri?

Tags: light, parent

I set a keyframe for my hdri location via texture coordinates.
now I wanna make it parent to my sun so that the sun follows the hdri location.
I tracked my sun to my object and now want to parent my hdri to my sun.
please let me know if there is away.If not,I will draw a path and sync the rotation by that.

but If there is a way to parent the world rotation to light please let me know.
in cycle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution (and probably needlessly complicated) is driving the Sun rotation from the HDRI

1. Add nodes to your HDRI Mapping node like in the second image
2. Go *Value node > RMB > Copy As New Driver* and paste as Sun's Z rotation
3. The *Value node* rotates both HDRI + Sun (for animating)
4. The *Add node* rotates only HDRI

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't see how it could get much simpler than that..:)

Comment: @Robin Thanks, it's always nice to have you check I didn't miss something obvious :).