# how do i connect a sun lamp to a sky texture with a sun in eevee 2.92?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine

Basically I want to find a way to link the rotation of a sun lamp to the rotation/position of my sky texture or at least link the sky texture to an empty and then link a sun lamp to that. Also, this sky texture is procedurally generated.

Comment: Related: [How to parent my sun to environment HDRI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/200074/78972)

Comment: I'll give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

Yea sorry I figured out by using this link as a guide, tho I did have to make some edits as I had an actual sun texture, course now I have to figure out how to make a moon texture.

[how to parent my sun to environment hdri?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200074/how-to-parent-my-sun-to-environment-hdri)